# Radio select for selecting the default value of many in a model admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a fairly simple foreign key relationship displayed by an inline in Django's admin:

```
# models
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField()
    is_default = models.BooleanField()

# admins
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class EmailAddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = EmailAddress

    inlines = (EmailAddressInline,)
```

I'd simply like to be able to select only *one* of the email addresses as `is_default`, using a radio button on the admin page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a case of a bad design. You should store the id of the default email in the profile table, so you can assure on database and program level that two email addresses for one profile won't be set to default. Give it a thought to change your database structure.

Comment: How would I display that in the admin, though? I'm looking to make a nice, easy-to-use admin site for data entry by non-developers.

Comment: If you used my design, it would not affect your UI, you could achieve exactly what you want. With this design I'm not sure. I'm not familiar with django, I use symfony2, which has quite similar principles as django, and thinking in symfony2 I could achieve this goal using my design but I couldn't using yours. That's all I can help. And what if two emails will be default for one profile(lets say because of a bug)? So I really want to convince you to change.

Comment: Believe me, I've _tried_ that method. Unfortunately, Django's admin system doesn't play too nicely. The only reason I'm asking this is because it _does not_ work to have `Person.default_email_address` and `Person.email_addresses`. There's simply no way to display it nicely in the admin.

Comment: I believe you, though, I'm not sure that the error "it does not display nicely" should be solved by a bad backend design. I would rather go for changing the template. Wait for a django guru, and see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

Small hint: Although it does not solve the radio button problem in the admin inline, this unique constraint ensures that there is only one default per profile in the data.

```
# models
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    address = models.EmailField()
    is_default = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['profile'],
                condition=Q(is_default=True),
                name='unique_default'
            ),
        ]
```